# How to redirect stderr to a file for the whole pipe?

Tags: bash, pipe, stderr

I am running a command like this:

```
mycmd1 | mycmd2 | mycmd3 | lp
```

Is there a way to redirect stderr to a file for the whole pipe instead of repeating it for each command?

That is to say, I'd rather avoid doing this:

```
mycmd1 2>/myfile | mycmd2 2>/myfile | mycmd3 2>/myfile | lp 2>/myfile
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either

```
{ mycmd1 | mycmd2 | mycmd3 | lp; } 2>> logfile
```

or

```
( mycmd1 | mycmd2 | mycmd3 | lp ) 2>> logfile
```

will work. (The first version might be have a slightly faster (~1ms) startup time depending on the shell).

Comment: `{ ...; }` is better because it doesn't create a subshell.

Comment: why are subshells undesirable?

Comment: @springloaded, subshells have a performance cost to create (the typical implementation is `fork()` -- exact cost varies by platform, but in a tight loop it's very nontrivial, and on Windows they tend to be expensive more widely). Beyond that, they impact variable scope: If you were in a shell where `lastpipe` were true, `lp` could be a command that changes shell variables in the `{ ... | lp; }` case but not the `( ... | lp )` case without those changes being silently lost when the subshell exits. See [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following, and it seems to work:

```
(mycmd1 | mycmd2 | mycmd3 | lp) 2>>/var/log/mylogfile.log
```

I use `>>` because I want to append to the logfile rather than overwriting it every time.